# What is wrong with this binding syntax: {Binding List[Index]}?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding

Given a data object: `{List = new Int32[] {0, 1, 2, 3}, Index = 2}` which I want to bind to a control using the following syntax:

```
{Binding List[Index]}
```

which doesn't work and doesn't throw any exceptions. I cannot see what is going on by attaching a converter to this binding either.

As long as I can do `{Binding List[0]}` why on earth this one doesn't work: `{Binding List[Index]}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use a MultiBinding with a converter for this, since Index itself needs to be binded.

E.g.

```
<MyControl>
  <MyControl.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource yourConverter}">
      <MultiBinding.Bindings>
        <Binding Path="List" />
        <Binding Path="Index" />
      </MultiBinding.Bindings>
    </MultiBinding>
  </MyControl.Text>
</MyControl>
```

And the converter:

```cs
public class NameConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length != 2 || !(values[0] is IList<MyItemType>) || !(values[1] is int))
            return Binding.DoNothing;

        var list = (IList<MyItemType>)values[0];
        var index = (int)values[1];

        if (index < 0 || index >= list.Count)
            return Binding.DoNothing;

        return list[index];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Multibinding solutions for Silverlight (courtesy of Google):

SL3: http://www.olsonsoft.com/blogs/stefanolson/post/Improvements-to-Silverlight-Multi-binding-support.aspx

SL4: http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/05/silverlight-multibinding-solution-for-silverlight-4/

SL5: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/286171/MultiBinding-in-Silverlight-5

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such thing as IMultiValueConverter in Silverlight by default. Would you mind giving an implementation based on IValueConverter

Comment: Great solution. MultiBinding didn't come to my mind, because natively it's not supported in Silverlight...

Answer (score 0):

The binding expressions are evaluated when the XAML is being parsed. Thus values used there have to be compile-time constants, so that they can be built into the expression that is later on used for the binding.

So one way to go would be to create a property on your ViewModel that exposes the item of the List you want to bind to.

Using a `ValueConverter` unfortunately also is no option here, because you cannot bind to the `ConverterParameter` of the binding expression, and thus the converter won't know the index either...